# How to change logo in Joomla template, Entropy?

Tags: joomla, themes

First time using Joomla and having a big issue.  I was able to locate the css files that contains the background image url for the logo but i can't find the path that the css is referring to:

```
      (../images/logo/style3/logo.png)
```

I am using the Entropy them by RocketThemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The urls that you found are are relative. The url of your image is therefore relative to the location of the css file you found. The ../ means go up one level - so instead of /templates/rt_entropy_j15/css/ (the location of the css file you are examining), one level up is /templates/rt_entropy_j15/ then go into the /images/ sub-folder (within /templates/rt_entropy_j15/ ) then navigate the /logo/style3/ folder tree and find your logo.png in place.

Firebug or similar debugging tools are always the best way to work through these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 3):

Your logo path is : `/templates/rt_entropy_j15/images/logo/style3/logo.png`

Comment: Whilst your answer is no doubt correct I can't help but feel it is better to 'teach a man to fish' than to just give him a fish.